# Accepting both http and https protocols on a single port, with SNI support on a Netty server

Tags: netty, netty4

As far as I know,
OptionalSslHandler is built for handing both protocols on the same port, while,
SniHandler is made for SNI handling.

Both handlers seem to handle all the complex handshake and negotiate steps, then inject a sslHandler in the pipeline.

I know this may not be a good idea, but I would like to know if it possible to add a SniHandler after OptionalSslHandler in Netty 4? like "OptionalSniHandler"...?

Maybe I could achieve it with overwriting OptionalSslHandler to add a SniHandler instead of SslHandler?

Thanks!!!

references:
[How does netty server supports both Http and Https protocols with a single port?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54284502/how-does-netty-server-supports-both-http-and-https-protocols-with-a-single-port)
[Determine which TLS version was negotiated by client to a Netty server, with SniHandler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68800325/determine-which-tls-version-was-negotiated-by-client-to-a-netty-server-with-sni)